# Jest's testRegex and testMatch

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between `testRegex` and `testMatch` in Jest configuration?
(https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration)

I understand that I should not define them both but in what situation shall I use one and not the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jest.testMatch` accepts an **array** of [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Like when you use `ls p*` to list every file in the current directory which starts with a `p`.

`jest.testRegex` accepts a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) **string**, which is way more powerful (but maybe an overkill for what you're trying to achieve).

I'd use the one you're more familiar with. It would be redundant to set both.

Although, for some complex cases, you are better off with a regex. If you want `jest` to only test files that start with a `p` and have exactly three numbers in fixed places and the filename ends with `.test` or `.jest`, go for a regex. But don't do that anyway.